# Javascript custom array sort by array

Tags: javascript

I currently have this function which sort an array alphabetically.

```
function compare(a,b) {
    if (a.subtitle < b.subtitle)
        return -1;
    if (a.subtitle > b.subtitle)
        return 1;
        return 0;
}
```

I need a similar function that sorts the array by another array. I tried writing it myself but i couldn't get my head around it so i ended up with nothing.

Example:

I need array1 to be sorted depending on where that item is in array2.

```
Array1 = ['quick','fox','the','brown'];
Array2 = ['the','quick','brown','fox'];
```

There is probably an easy answer that i am not seeing.

**Edit:**

Also any items that are in array1 that aren't in array 2 can just be tacked onto the end in no particular order or alphabetically whatever is easier.

Comment: Note that `return 0;` is the default here, and the indentation is deceptive. For this reason, use curly-braces with if-statements in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function compare(a,b, compareArray) {
    if ((compareArray.indexOf(a) != -1 && compareArray.indexOf(a) < compareArray.indexOf(b))
         ||  compareArray.indexOf(b) == -1)
        return -1;
    if ((compareArray.indexOf(a) > compareArray.indexOf(b))
         || compareArray.indexOf(a) == -1)
        return 1;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which array is compareArray?

Comment: `compareArray` would be `Array2` in your question.

Comment: That's good, however you should create an index map for quick lookups.

Comment: Does this handle items that aren't in array2?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AMSDE/

```
var Array1 = ['quick', 'fox', 'the', 'brown', 'abc']; //the array to be sorted
var Array2 = ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'];
var sortedAry = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Array2.length; i++) {
var index = Array1.indexOf(Array2[i]);
if (index !== -1) {
    console.log(index);
    sortedAry.push(Array2[i]);
    Array1.splice(index, 1);
}
}

for (var j = 0; j < Array1.length; j++) {
sortedAry.push(Array1[j]);
}

console.log(sortedAry);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the need to do the same thing today, this was my solution:

```
var arr = [".", 5359, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 15];
var priorities = [3, '.', 1, 4, 15, 9, 2, 6];

var resultArr = arr.filter( function(arrElement) { return priorities.indexOf(arrElement) >= 0 })
    .sort( function (a,b) { return priorities.indexOf(a) - priorities.indexOf(b) })
    .concat( arr.filter( function(arrElement) { return priorities.indexOf(arrElement) < 0})
);

console.log(resultArr.join(""));
```

console: `3.14159265359`

[jsfiddle based on @rps's answer](http://jsfiddle.net/jz8kpmmc/)

Basically, it picks out the elements that we have a preferred order for, sorts those, then appends the elements that we had no order preference for. As a bonus (at least for my use case), the sorting is non-destructive to the order of `arr`.

I'm not sure if this is better or worse, but I know I loathe `for` loops. :)